# Print PHP a table with sql selection

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

my problem is a little bit hard to explain, in that case I do not know for what I should search.

I've got a MySQL-Database. It looks like this:

```
Name   |   Identification
--------------------------
"abc"  |   1
"def"  |   1
"ghi"  |   5
"jkl"  |   1
"mno"  |   19
"pqr"  |   7
```

and so on.
 I want to display a table like this:
[image]

How can I reach this? I am using mysqli.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: where do you want to display the table - as sql result?

Comment: Use PHP to connect to the DB using mysqli. Build your SQL string. Send the SQL to the database. Retrieve the result. Display the result on a web page. You really couldn't find info about any of those steps online?? It's the most basic thing in a web application. There are literally hundreds of tutorials on the subject, even when you restrict it to PHP with MySQLi.

Comment: Wide off the mark: Use PDO class instead of mysqli function in PHP. It will provide you better security, modularity, an OOP way for your queries. You will be able to change your database driver in future also.

Comment: @Huelfe no, as an PHP table.

Comment: @ADyson I know how to retrieve Data from an Database. The problem is how to get the names grouped by the identification. GROUP BY only uses one name then.

Comment: @KorayKüpe I will read me into this.

Comment: What do you mean with PHP table? Do you mean HTML?

Comment: Yes, an table written in html with php(database) content. Like the picture above.

Comment: don't do it with group by. Do it when you render the table. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp is what you need. If you already knew how to do all that stuff why didn't you say so and make the question specific to your problem? It sounded like "how do I do the whole thing", not just an issue with the presentation of the specific part of the data.

Comment: I'm so sorry, no the problem is indeed just displaying the table. Getting the content would be no problem. And how can I set the "identification" once in a table cell, and the "name"s in more than one cell?

Comment: did you read about "rowspan" that I linked to? That lets you create a cell that goes across multiple rows, just like your picture. The rest is just some looping logic to work out in PHP. Make an attempt, and then if you can't get it working properly then post your code and we can try to fix it. You won't get anyone giving you the whole thing from scratch on SO, that's not how the site works.